# Adding to SQL server database in angular 2 and MVC

Tags: typescript, model-view-controller, crud, angular2-forms

I'm trying to insert a value to Employee table in the SQL server of Microsoft, using angular and MVC.

The following code is the addEmployee component:

```
 private EmpId: number;
             public formData: FormGroup;
             public constructor(private empService: EmployeeServices) {
                    this.empService.postData(this.EmpId)
                        .subscribe(
                        (data: Response) =>  (data.json())
                     );

             this.formData = new FormGroup({
                        'EmployeeName': new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
                        'EmployeeSalary': new FormControl('',[Validators.required])   
                    });

                }

                onSubmit() {
                    if (this.formData.valid) {
                        var Obj = {
                            EmployeeName: this.formData.value.EmployeeName,
                            EmployeeSalary: this.formData.value.EmployeeSalary,
                        };
                        this.empService.postData(Obj).subscribe();
                        alert("Employee Inserted Successfully");
                    }

                }
```

However, when I try to run it nothing happens and the value I entered are not posted in the database.

My controller is :

```
[HttpPost]
    public IActionResult AddEmployee([FromBody]Employee empObj)
    {
        _context.Employee.Add(empObj);
        _context.SaveChanges();
        return Json("OK");
     }
```

And the service is :

```
 postData(empObj: any) {
    let headers = new Headers({
        'Content-Type':
        'application/json; charset=utf-8'
    });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:65291/api/employee', JSON.stringify(empObj), options);
}
```

What can I write in the add component to let the system add to the database successfully?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, place a breakpoint in your controller function to make sure the function is being fired.

Secondly, your url

```
'http://localhost:65291/api/**employee**'
```

and controller function name don't match

```
public IActionResult **AddEmployee**()
```